# How to take a string and read it for an array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

Im having trouble finding out how to read letters and turn them into numbers like -1 and 1.
Here's the context:

I'm working on a word problem for my Java programming class. I'm asked to create a program in Java that receives input of a number of "L"s or "R"s, short for left or right. For each L the program should go one spot back in an array, and for each R it should go one spot forward. Like if you start at 0, and get an input of RR, it should move to be at 2. Hopefully that makes sense, here's a diagram to hopefully clarify.[image: Example array]

Now, what I don't understand is how to take the input from using Scanner(System.in) that gives me the L/R combination (eg. LLR) and turn that into the series of directions for the program (eg. -1,-1,+1). How do i specify that the input of an L is equal to going one space back? And vice versa for any R's input into the program?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks a ton

Edit: Heres the current code I have:

```
import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.text.*;
    import java.math.*;
    import java.util.regex.*;

    public class Solution {
        public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
            int max = 100;
            int min = 1;
            int posMax = 10000;
            int posMin = -10000;
            boolean dataExists = false;
            
            String inputData;
            int initialPosition;
            System.out.println("Insert sequence of commands (L and R)");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            inputData = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Input starting position");
            initialPosition = input.nextInt();
            
        }
    }
```

What it does it it defines the minimum and maximum commands (left and rights, which is 1-100) and the min and max positions which are -10000 and 10000. The next part would have been recieving the string of L's and R's and reading them to change the array but thats where im stuck.

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @TimMoore Done! Please let me know if theres anything else, thanks for the reply!

Comment: Great. So, what does `inputData` contain at the end of the method? If you’re not sure, you can print it out.

Comment: @TimMoore Hello! The inputData string would holt he L's and R's

Comment: Do you have more code following the line `initialPosition = input.nextInt();`?  Are you going to be getting a `String` from `input`? Do you know how to get one character from a `String`?

Comment: @James I do not have any further code. It would be asking for the input of a string like LRLRRLR and then it should go back and forth as it checks that string. Is that what you mean by get a character from a string?

Comment: Take a look at a [`Scanner` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) page. Take a look at the `next` methods. You use your `Scanner` (called `input` in your program) to read a `String`.

Comment: Here is a [`String` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) page. One method that might interest you is `charAt(int index)`.

Comment: @James thanks a ton! ill check into those now, i appreciate the resources!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of Scanner.nextLine() is a String Object.
You can split up this String Object to a char array and check if the char is a 'L', 'R', or something else.

```
String cmds = "RRRRRLLLRLRLLRLRLLRLLRLRL";
char[] cCmds = cmds.toCharArray();
int pos = 39;
for (char c : cCmds) {
    switch (c) {
        case 'L' -> pos--;
        case 'R' -> pos++;
        default -> System.out.println("That was not an L or R...");
    }
}
System.out.println("Position: " + pos);
```

Next step would now to add some conditions to check if the user input was too long or too short.

```
if (cmds.length() > MAX_INPUT || cmds.length() < MIN_INPUT) {
    System.out.println("User input was too long or too short");
    return;
}
```

The last step now is to check if you can move to another position each time if you want to move.

```
 case 'L' -> { if (pos > POS_MIN) pos--; }
 case 'R' -> { if (pos < POS_MAX) pos++; }
```

All in one, it would look like this (with Scanner):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    static final int MIN_INPUT = 1;
    static final int MAX_INPUT = 100;

    static final int POS_MIN = -10000;
    static final int POS_MAX = 10000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Insert sequence of commands (L and R)");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String cmds = input.nextLine();

        if (cmds.length() > MAX_INPUT || cmds.length() < MIN_INPUT) {
            System.out.println("User input was too long or short");
            return;
        }

        System.out.println("Input starting position");
        int pos = input.nextInt();

        char[] cCmds = cmds.toCharArray();
        for (char c : cCmds) {
            switch (c) {
                case 'L' -> { if (pos > POS_MIN) pos--; }
                case 'R' -> { if (pos < POS_MAX) pos++; }
                default -> System.out.println("That was not an L or R...");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Position: " + pos);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind to catch the exception which the Scanner Object can cause.
(e.g. when scanner.nextInt() gets non Integer user input)

And also add a check if the user input for the initial position is in the given range.

Comment: Holy smokes, thank you! I had no idea about .toCharArray(), I have a lot to learn.

Comment: Hey @Anker, Follow up question, how would i have it print the amount of unique positions it passed over instead of the new position?
For example starting at 0 with LLR, it would go to -1,-2.then -1 meaning there are 3 unique positions (0,-1,-2) and it would output 3.

Would I have to put each position in a new array?

Comment: @itsacode001 you can not skip a number as you only move +1/-1, so it would be enough to safe the lowest and highest number you reached and calculate the difference.